# How to recreate deleted diagnostic directory for grid user (oradiag_grid)

Tags: linux, oracle, redhat

I deleted a diagnostic folder named "oradiag_grid" which was automatically created when the "grid" user was created (for Oracle Grid Infrastructure user).
Below is the command used in creating the grid user account:

## /usr/sbin/useradd -u 54331 -g oinstall -G dba,asmdba,backupdba,dgdba,kmdba,racdba grid

Below is the path of the directory that was deleted:

/home/grid/oradiag_grid

Here are the what it contains:
.../oradiag_grid/diag/asmtool/user_grid/host__110

Uderneath /host__110, you get the following directories:

alert,
cdump,
incident,
incpkg,
lck,
log,
metadata,
metadata_dgif,
metadata_pv,
stage,
sweep,
trace

I've searched but can't find an answer; is there a command to recreate this directories with it's sub-directories? I can't simply recreate it as the host_ten digit number_110 is system generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid Control should create the directory structure automatically when needed. So as long as `/home/grid` is writable by `root` and `grid` users, the directory should be created.